# are *-homomorphisms from a C* algebra to the bounded linear operators on some Hilbert space continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-algebras

I've been trying to prove that a star-homomorphism T:A to B(H) is continuous, where A is a C*-algebra and B(H) is the bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space. It's proving a real nightmare are there are some proofs which seem solid, but fall through on the details - eg some proofs use spectral radius = norm, but this only holds for normal operators.

Someone please let me know if this is actually worth trying to prove!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, any $^{\ast}$-homomorphism $f : A \to B$ between (edit: unital) C*-algebras is automatically continuous.

*Proof.* This is a standard argument. If $a - \lambda I$ is invertible then so is $f(a - \lambda I) = f(a) - \lambda I$; it follows that the spectrum satisfies $\sigma(f(a)) \subseteq \sigma(a)$, so the spectral radius satisfies $\rho(f(a)) \le \rho(a)$. Now, for every $a \in A$ we have

$$\| f(a) \| = \sqrt{ \| f(a)^{\ast} f(a) \| } = \sqrt{ \rho(f(a^{\ast} a)) } \le \sqrt{ \rho(a^{\ast} a)} = \| a \|$$

so $f$ has norm $\le 1$ and in particular is continuous. The use of the C*-identity here is what allows us to use the spectral radius even though $a$ and $f(a)$ are not guaranteed to be normal. $\Box$

Comment: You assume several things: that $A$ and $B$ are unital and that $f$ preserves the unit. Of course, standard arguments allow us to reduce to this case, but I think your answer should at least spend one sentence about this.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: ah yeah, I assume that algebras are unital by default but I guess that's not a safe assumption for C*-algebras. How do you define the spectrum of an element of a C*-algebra in the absence of a unit? Passing to the unitization?

Comment: Yes by viewing the element as an element in the unitisation and considering the spectrum there (in fact, it does not matter in which kind of unitisation you consider the spectrum, a nice thing about C*-algebras).